# Cannot cast object of type ContentPage to type ContentPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, casting

So I am currently working on my first Xamarin application.
I have a MasterDetailPage with a menu, and when you click on one of the menu items on the left the below I save the object I am working with (to the file system), I create a new 'ContentPage' for the page they have chosen and pass in the object as a constructor parameter.

I then attempt to set the MasterDetailPage Detail object to (ContentPage)obj which is a cast of the content page they have chosen.

[image: ContentPage class]

Now as you can see, the base for the JobDetails is a ContentPage, yet I cannot cast it to content page!?

[image: obj object]

I have also tried casting to Page instead to no avail.

Am I missing some fundamental knowledge when it comes to casting, or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this.
The issue wasn't with the Content Page cast (casting from obj > content page) but was because I had some xaml which wasn't correct inside JobDetails page.

The offending xaml was a

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="KeySkillsList">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>

                            <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsToggled="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"></Switch>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

This was due to me misunderstanding the list view (and the switch!)
The actual offending line specifically was the , commented out the page works.

I have now changed this so that its just a normal list view, with 1 switchcell, with a Text property.